# Hide data that are only partly shown on display

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am currently working on making a log file that would display its data on a screen (edit : from an html file). Each log should be either completely shown or hidden.

As you can see on this image I have a problem with some test logs : they can be partly shown. In this case I would want the 12/01/22 log line to not be displayed at all because the text is cut in half at the bottom. Any idea on how to do this please ?

[image]

My current code is :

```
# Function to display log line by line 
def intersperse(lst, item):
result = [item] * (len(lst) * 2 - 1)
result[0::2] = lst
return result

# Getting data
test = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    x = row['Date'] + ' | ' + row['Description'] + ' | ' + row['Titre de la consigne'] + ' | ' + row['Prenom'] + ' | ' + row['Choix des equipements 1'] + ' | ' + row['Choix des equipements 2'] + ' | ' + row['Prenom'] + '\r\n'
    test.append(x)

# Passing them into the function
data = intersperse(test, html.Br())
```

Edit : the html-Dash code (the rightboard is contained inside the dashboard) :

```
app.layout = html.Div(
className='dashboard',
style={"display":"flex","border":"1px black solid", 'width':'1850px','height':'920px'},
children=[

   html.Div(
       className='rightboard',
       style={'width':'100%','height':'100%',"border":"1px black solid", "overflow-wrap": "break-word", "overflow": "hidden"},
       children=[
           html.P(data)
   ])
])
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is this the full code? Where is the log actually being printed?

Comment: I added the html-dash code, sorry

Comment: Oh, I thought this was being printed to a terminal, I can not help with HTML unfortunately :(